# How to implement Canvas for spidermonkey

Tags: javascript, spidermonkey

Could anyone point me in the direction of how to to get a Canvas working with SpiderMonkey?

I intent to make a canvas implementation of my own. But I couldn't quite figure out how I can connect my canvas class with SpiderMonkey.

I am in need of guidance. Please help.